# Stochastic Gradient Descent in Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement stochastic gradient descent from scratch in Python in order to predict a specific polynomial function. I feel like I got the correct overall structure, but my weights (thetas) are apparently not updating correctly. This is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

def epsilon():
    '''Adds noise to the data points'''
    return np.random.normal(0, 0.3, 100)

def yFunction(x):
    '''Function to predict'''
    return np.sin(2 * math.pi * x) + epsilon()

def predict(x, thetas):
    '''Predict value of x with the given thetas'''
    prediction = 0
    for i in range(thetas.size):
        prediction += (x ** i) * thetas[i]
    return prediction

# learning rate
alpha = 0.1

# generate random data points
X = np.random.random_sample(100)
y = yFunction(X)

# init weights
thetas = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, 3)

# init loss history
lossHistory = []

for epoch in range(1000):
    # predict
    prediction = predict(X[epoch % 100], thetas)

    # calculate loss
    error = prediction - y[epoch % 100]
    loss = np.sum(error ** 2)

    # update thetas
    if error <= 0:
        thetas += alpha * loss
    else:
        thetas -= alpha * loss

    # log current loss
    lossHistory.append(loss)

# final predictions based on trained model
Y = predict(X, thetas)

# plot the original data along with our line of best fit
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X, Y, "r-")
plt.suptitle("Prediction line over actual values")

# construct a figure that plots the loss over time
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(0, len(lossHistory)), lossHistory)
fig.suptitle("Training Loss")
plt.show()
```

These are the resulting graphs:

[image: Python script results]

I would assume that I have to update weights independently rather than adding/subtracting a single amount per epoch, but I'm not sure how I would split the loss properly.

Comment: A good (and easy) experiment you could (and arguably should) do yourself first, is try to see the result given by an existing implementation - say, scikit-learn's linear regression model - and compare the results (plot & coefficients) with what you get here; it is my impression that your plot is not really off...

Comment: The thing is that I'm not looking for a linear solution. As you can see in my `predict` function, I'm using polynomials to multiply with my weights. So I'd want my solution to be a curve that fits a lot better to my generated data set.

Comment: OK, then maybe https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html ?

Comment: I explicitly want to write this from scratch without any libraries. I'm pretty sure it's possible, if I can change weights independently of each other. Right now, I'm assigning random start values and then change all of their values by the same amount per epoch